# Hbase Schema Nested Entity

Tags: hadoop, schema, hbase

Does anyone have an example on how to create an Hbase table with a nested entity?

Example

```
UserName (string)
SSN  (string)
  + Books (collection)
```

The books collection would look like this for example

Books

```
isbn
title
etc...
```

I cannot find a single example are how to create a table like this.  I see many people talk about it, and how it is a best practice in certain scenarios, but I cannot find an example on how to do it anywhere.

Thanks...

Comment: You could just do UserName_SSN_Books. Depends on your use case and what sort of queries you plan to run against it though.

Comment: NO, I want to store the collection (entity) nested in the main.  I am not looking to create two separate tables.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant. I see @ian-varley has put together an excellent answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nested entities isn't an official feature of HBase; it's just a way some people talk about one usage pattern. In this pattern, you use the fact that "columns" in HBase are really just a big map (a bunch of key/value pairs) to let you to model a dimension of cardinality *inside* the row by adding one column per "row" of the nested entity.

Schema-wise, you don't need to do much on the table itself; when you create a table in HBase, you just specify the name & column family (and associated properties), like so (in hbase shell):

```
hbase:001:0> create 'UserWithBooks', 'cf1'
```

Then, it's up to you what you put in it, column wise. You could insert values like:

```
hbase:002:0> put 'UsersWithBooks', 'userid1234', 'cf1:username', 'my username'
hbase:003:0> put 'UsersWithBooks', 'userid1234', 'cf1:ssn', 'my ssn'
hbase:004:0> put 'UsersWithBooks', 'userid1234', 'cf1:book_id_12345', '<isbn>12345</isbn><title>mary had a little lamb</title>'
hbase:005:0> put 'UsersWithBooks', 'userid1234', 'cf1:book_id_67890', '<isbn>67890</isbn><title>the importance of being earnest</title>'
```

The column names are totally up to you, and there's no limit to how many you can have (within reason: see the HBase Reference Guide for more on this). Of course, doing this, you have to do your own legwork re: putting in and getting out values (and you'd probably do it with the java client in a more sophisticated way than I'm doing with these shell commands, they're just for explanatory purposes). And while you can efficiently scan just a portion of the columns in a table by key (using a column pagination filter), you can't do much with the contents of the cells other than pull them and parse them elsewhere.

Why would you do this? Probably just if you wanted atomicity around all the nested rows for one parent row. It's not very common, your best bet is probably to start by modeling them as separate tables, and only move to this approach if you really understand the tradeoffs.

Comment: [Ian's talk at HBaseCon 2012](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/resources/library/hbasecon/video-hbasecon-2012-hbasecon-2012.html) has a bunch of examples too.  Start watching about 15min into the presentation for nested entities.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations to this. First, this technique only works to
one level deep: your nested entities can’t themselves have nested entities. You can still
have multiple different nested child entities in a single parent, and the column qualifier is their identifying attributes.
Second, it’s not as efficient to access an individual value stored as a nested column
qualifier inside a row, as compared to accessing a row in another table, as you learned
earlier in the chapter. 
Still, there are compelling cases where this kind of schema design is appropriate. If
the only way you get at the child entities is via the parent entity, and you’d like to have transactional protection around all children of a parent, this can be the right way to go.