# Storing Nested HashMap in HBase

Tags: hbase, bigtable, bigdata

Pardon my ignorance but I'm relatively new to HBase and can't seem to figure it out. I want to store the following nested HashMap in HBase:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>
```

I can't seem to figure out the schema of the HBase table.

Row Index will obviously be the String Value in the outermost Map. However, I don't think that HBase allows nested column families (although it does allow any number of columns per column family)

Also from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22125011/1332390) I found out that nested entities can't have nested entities in HBase.

To give you an idea of the data size:

1. The innermost Map (`Map<String, Double>`) will have 3 keys only.
2. The middle Map (`Map<String, Map<String, Double>>`) will have around
   100 keys.
3. The outermost Map (`Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>`)
   could have around 20-30 million keys.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1:
Basically, the quantity that I want to store is for particular productId, how many quantities were sold across local, zonal or national level from a particular warehouse.

- productId is the key for outermost Map.
- warehouseID is the key for the middle Map.
- local/zonal/national is the key for the innermost Map.

Edit 2:
Data will be populated and read inside a mapred job. Basically for each product id, warehouseId x (Local/Zonal/National : let's call it saleType for now) quantity is required as an input for another operation. I was also thinking of storing the data at productId x warehouseId x saleType granularity in a csv file and read it from a mapred job

Comment: stop! :) What's the problem statement? What are you trying to store (a nested hashmap doesn't tell me much)? What are your access patterns? Suggested read (all of it): http://hbase.apache.org/book.html

Comment: Does the above edit help a little bit?

Comment: it does. now, how are you planning to read the data? what kind of operation do you expect to be more common? also, your data is not 'too big' as of now, have you explored other options? I'm trying to determine if that 'obviously' is the source of your issues...

Comment: Data will be populated and read inside a mapred job. Basically for each product id, warehouseId x (Local/Zonal/National : let's call it saleType for now) quantity is required as an input for another operation. I was also thinking of storing the data at productId x warehouseId x saleType granularity in a csv file and read it from a mapred job.

Comment: My 2c on this: If you don't need random access then I would put in plain hdfs probably...

Answer (score 3):

Given your edits I would avoid using HBase (although I love it). It seems that you don't need random access to your data and doing a full table scan and full table write at each iteration is not the best use of HBase.

I'm assuming that you already have a Hadoop cluster. The best option is probably storing the data in a flat format directly in HDFS (A [SequenceFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html), [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/), or other serialization formats). Also, I'm not sure what kind of tools you use but I'm guessing that for basic count aggregation then [Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) would be a simple starting option).

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about this problem is (key1, key2, key3) -> double map.  You have keys, column families and qualifiers as ways to describe your structure.  You can put all 3 parts of the key tuple as a concatenated row_key for a really tall table, although that wouldn't work very well.

you have up to 9 billion tuples.  You have a good idea about the data.  The first question I would have from there, is: "how will you query and access the data most often?"  If you are looking for specific values and not sets, then perhaps 9 billion rows make sense.  If more often then not, you're looking for all of the inner data for a single outer key, then perhaps the outermost key as a row_key, and (middle)_(inner) as a column qualifier could work.  In the latter case, you can use QualifierFilter with a regex comparator to further filter the response.

Comment: Data will be populated and read inside a mapred job. Basically for each product id, warehouseId x (Local/Zonal/National : let's call it saleType for now) quantity is required as an input for another operation. I was also thinking of storing the data at productId x warehouseId x saleType granularity in a csv file and read it from a mapred job

Comment: If you're processing all of the data, a CSV file might work better.  I'm not sure you'd need HBase.  If the CSV file or files is significantly easier than hbase, I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have large data set, scope for partitions and also requires fast retrieval, so you can make use of [parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) format on HDFS.
Which will provide you a columnar storage with partitions and compression support.
Also you can read the data through any other frameworks like spark, drill etc.